# What does "Fill Increment" mean with SAGA - Fill Sinks (QM of ESP) tool?

Tags: qgis, saga, depression-filling

I am using the SAGA tool Fill Sinks (QM of ESP). The only adjustable parameter is called "Fill Increment". And the [documentation](https://saga-gis.sourceforge.io/saga_tool_doc/2.2.5/sim_qm_of_esp_1.html) is not very explicit about what it means. Is it the depth from which a sink must be filled ? Is it an angle ? In which unit ?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, and a fair bit of digging to get this:
https://github.com/LSDtopotools/LSDTopoTools_CRNBasinwide/blob/master/LSDRaster.cpp
Line 6788:
"This function fills pits/sinks in a DEM by incrementing elevations for cells with no downslope neighbour. The process is repeated ad nausium until no cells require incrementing. Inputs required are a DEM file in ascii raster format as created by ARCMap and a file name to create a filled DEM grid. This code was built on top of code made available by Jon D. Pelletier as part of his book: Pelletier,J.D.,'Quantitative Modelling of Landscapes' Cambridge University Press."
So it looks like the number is elevation, or 0.01m for my DEM, which with this modification was reduced from 1cm to 1mm.
"v1.3 reduced fill increment to 1mm  to avoid 'overfilling'
Martin Hurst, October 2011"

Or this could be it, in which case 0.01 is slope...% or degrees?
"New fill function
This function fills pits/sinks in a DEM by checking for pits from lowest to highest elevation, starting at the DEM boundary (raster edge or adjacent to NDVs). Utilises a priority queue to progressively populate the stack and pop out the the lowest value before checking that the neighbouring cells that are yet to be visited must be higher in a hydrologically correct DEM. This method is substantially faster on datasets with pits consisting of multiple cells since each cell only needs to be visited once.
Input argument required -> MinSlope the minimum slope between two Nodes once filled
If set to zero will create flats.
Method taken from Wang and Liu (2006), Int. J. of GIS. 20(2), 193-213"